# Spring Integration Kafka Manual Acknowledgment

Tags: spring-integration, apache-kafka

I'm having issues using manual acknowledgements with the KafkaTopicOffsetManager. When acknowledge() is called, the topic begins to get spammed repeatedly. Kafka has log.cleaner.enable set to true and the topic is using cleanup.policy=compact. Thanks for any help.

Config:

```
@Bean
public ZookeeperConfiguration zookeeperConfiguration() {
    ZookeeperConfiguration zookeeperConfiguration = new ZookeeperConfiguration(kafkaConfig.getZookeeperAddress());
    zookeeperConfiguration.setClientId("clientId");
    return zookeeperConfiguration;
}

@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    return new DefaultConnectionFactory(zookeeperConfiguration());
}

@Bean
public TestMessageHandler messageListener() {
    return new TestMessageHandler();
}

@Bean
public OffsetManager offsetManager() {
    ZookeeperConnect zookeeperConnect = new ZookeeperConnect(kafkaConfig.getZookeeperAddress());
    OffsetManager offsetManager = new KafkaTopicOffsetManager(zookeeperConnect, kafkaConfig.getTopic() + "_OFFSET");

    return offsetManager;
}

@Bean
public KafkaMessageListenerContainer kafkaMessageListenerContainer() {
    KafkaMessageListenerContainer kafkaMessageListenerContainer = new KafkaMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory(), kafkaConfig.getTopic());
    kafkaMessageListenerContainer.setMessageListener(messageListener());
    kafkaMessageListenerContainer.setOffsetManager(offsetManager());
    return kafkaMessageListenerContainer;
}
```

Listener:

```
public class TestMessageHandler implements AcknowledgingMessageListener {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestMessageHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void onMessage(KafkaMessage message, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
        logger.info(message.toString());

        acknowledgment.acknowledge();
    }
}
```

Comment: The KafkaTopicOffsetManager needs its own topic to maintain the offset of the actual topic being consumed. Updated with proper config to help anyone else struggling with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KafkaTopicOffsetManager needs its own topic to maintain the offset of the actual topic being consumed.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to deal with decoding the message payload yourself (its painful in my opinion), extend listener from abstract class AbstractDecodingAcknowledgingMessageListener and provide org.springframework.integration.kafka.serializer.common.StringDecoder as the decoder.

```
public class TestMessageHandlerDecoding extends AbstractDecodingAcknowledgingMessageListener {

public TestMessageHandlerDecoding(Decoder keyDecoder, Decoder payloadDecoder) {
    super(keyDecoder, payloadDecoder);
}

@Override
public void doOnMessage(Object key, Object payload, KafkaMessageMetadata metadata, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
    LOGGER.info("payload={}",payload);

}
```